# Evaluating an integral using residue theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, proof-verification, residue-calculus

I'm evaluating $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_C \frac{e^{zt}}{z(z^2+1)}dz$, $t > 0$ where $C$ is defined by the vertices $2+2i$, $-2+2i$, $-2-2i$, and $2-2i$.  I'm pretty sure this is done by finding the poles in $C$ and the residues at the poles and then adding them together, but the answer is supposed to be $1-\cos t$.  Here is what I've done:

$$\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint_Cf(z)dz=a_{-1}$$
$$a_{-1}=\lim_{z \to a}\frac{1}{(m-1)!}\frac{d^{m-1}}{dz^{m-1}}\{(z-a)^mf(z)\}$$

The poles are found where $z(z^2+1)$ would be zero, which are $z=0,i,-i$.  I need to take the above limit as $z$ goes to each pole.
$$\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{1}{0!}\frac{d^0}{dz^0}\{(z-0)^1\frac{e^{zt}}{z(z^2+1)}\}=\lim_{z \to 0}\frac{e^{zt}}{z^2+1}=1$$

$$\lim_{z \to i}\frac{1}{0!}\frac{d^0}{dz^0}\{(z-i)^1\frac{e^z}{z(z^2+1)}\}=\lim_{z \to i}\frac{e^{zt}+(z-i)e^{zt}t}{2z}=\frac{e^{it}}{2i}$$

$$\lim_{z \to -i}\frac{1}{0!}\frac{d^0}{dz^0}\{(z+i)^1\frac{e^z}{z(z^2+1)}\}=\lim_{z \to -i}\frac{e^{zt}+(z+i)e^{zt}t}{2z}=\frac{e^{-it}}{-2i}$$

If I were correct, the answer would be $1+\frac{e^{it}}{2i}-\frac{e^{-it}}{2i}$.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you made a simple mistake in evaluating the second limit, which can be rewritten as:

$\lim_{z\to i}\frac{(z-i)e^{zt}}{z(z+i)(z-i)} = -\frac{1}{2}e^{it}$ so you missed a minus sign

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I was just giving it another try, and realized there were a few mistakes and typos, including taking a derivative incorrectly when applying L'Hopital's rule.  So the sum of residues should be $1-\frac{e^{it}}{2}-\frac{e^{-it}}{2}$ according to what I have done.  I suspect (hope) this can be worked around to the correct answer, but am currently struggling with this.

Comment: You may have forgotten: $$\frac{e^{it}+ e^{-it}}{2}=\cos t.$$